# Displaying data from local SQL Server CE database in a gridview C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I am working on a small application for personal use. It is about keeping some data readily available for me.

It just consists of a local database, functions to add, erase or modify 4 or 5 columns of data and displaying the table in a datagridview.

I have managed to add data to the table and I have managed to use a

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

statement to get the data and iterate through it but I want to bind the table to the datagridview.

Here is my current method of trying to bind the data:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
   SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(conString);

   using (SqlCeDataAdapter adap = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, conn))
   {
       //the adapter will open and close the connection for you.
       DataTable dat = new DataTable();
       adap.Fill(dat);
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dat;
   }
}
```

When I run this code it does not throw an exception and if I change the name of the table to something that does not exists then it causes an exception telling that the table does not exists so I know that it is fetching my table. It simply is not showing it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your connection string, please? And possibly look in bin/debug for a copy of your database file.

Comment: I have my connection string set by Visual Studio in the settings file. Here is how I retreive it: string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.tvdataConnectionString;

Comment: My database file?  Is it the tvdata.sdf ?

Comment: wrap that code in a try/catch block...but my guess is the connection string has something wrong.

Comment: I will try that but it would throw an exception if something was wrong without the try / catch block, which it does not. Like I say, if I change the table name in the SELECT statement then it throws an error that the table does not exist.

Comment: Yeah. The try / catch does nothing, because there is no error being thrown.

Comment: then please wrap the 3 lines of code,where you create the datatable and do the fill and set datagridview datasource,inside this if statement if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) then place a breakpoint and see if it enters.

Comment: I did, it does NOT enter :/

Comment: then problem is with connectionstring...most certainly :),in serverexplorer select your database and in the properties window there is the correct connection string.

Comment: I thought the "using" would take care of that for me. Now I open the connection before the IF block and then it enters.

Comment: then all is well now?...well not the adapter itself but the fill method is the one that  opens the connection...if still not working check my comment above about the connectionstring.

Comment: Yeah it is all well for now. I will keep this question unanswered until a bit later. If there is nothing else then I will pick the appropriate answer. Thanks for your help.